# problems implementing negamax for tic-tac-toe in ruby

Tags: ruby, tic-tac-toe

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to implement negamax for tic-tac-toe

```
def negamax(board_obj, mark, depth)
  if board_obj.game_over?
    return value(board_obj)
  else
    max = -1.0/0 # negative infinity
    if mark == @mark
      next_mark = @opponent_mark
    else
      next_mark = @mark
    end
    board_obj.empty_squares.each do |square|
      board_obj[square] = mark
      x = -negamax(board_obj, next_mark, depth + 1)
      board_obj[square] = ' '
      if x > max
        max = x
        @scores << x
        @best_move = square if depth == 1
      end
    end
    return max
  end
end

# determines value of final board state
def value(board_obj)
  if board_obj.mark_win?(@mark)
    return 1
  elsif  board_obj.mark_win?(@opponent_mark)
    return -1
  else
    return 0
  end
end
```

the rest of the code is here: https://github.com/dave-maldonado/tic-tac-doh/blob/AI/tic-tac-doh.rb

It does produce a result but the AI is easily beat so I know something's wrong, any help
is appreciated!

Comment: What are your thoughts to what's wrong? Stackoverflow doesn't do great with code just thrown at us. But we're happy to help if you can give us some specific questions

Comment: What are you using for your reference implementation of the negamax function?

Comment: was initially following http://www.hamedahmadi.com/gametree/#negamax for my implementation but instead of making a copy of the board object before each iteration I'm undo-ing the move after the recursion. I put some print statements to try and figure out what's going on, I think value is working correctly, states that are a win for the AI return 1, player returns -1 and draws return 0 but something's not working right because the AI will return non-sensical moves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `value` needs to be relative to the `mark` in the current execution of `negamax` rather than always relative to the computer. If you pass in the `mark` argument to `value` from `negamax` with the following modified definition for `value`, you'll get the right results:

```
def value(board_obj, mark)
  if board_obj.mark_win?(mark)
    return 1
  elsif  board_obj.mark_win?(mark == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X')
    return -1
  else
    return 0
  end
end
```

That is, the first two lines of the `negamax` body need to be:

```
if board_obj.game_over?
  return value(board_obj, mark)
```

That said, this overall program leaves an awful lot to be desired relative to Ruby, good design principles, etc (no offense intended). Now that you have it running, you might want to head over to the Code Review SE for some feedback. :-)  And while it's too late to use TDD ;-), it would also be a good one to put "under test".

Also, please understand that per one of the other comments, this is not a kind of question that you'll typically get an answer to here at SO. I don't even know if this question will survive the review process without getting deleted. I worked on it for a variety of personal reasons.

Update: Looking at your reference implementation, you'll note that the negamax code includes the expression `sign[color]*Analysis(b)`. It's that `sign[color]` that you were missing, effectively.

Comment: You're very welcome. Thanks for accepting. Feel free to "upvote" if you'd like. It would put me over 1k rep and I'd always remember how I got there (if the question survives). ;-)

Comment: I'm new to SO, as soon as I get the 15 rep needed I'll up vote for sure

Comment: :-) Didn't know there was a minimum for that. Good luck.